Can I install 18.04 from within Ubuntu 24.04 on a free 1GB partition I have on the same drive?
Can I install Ubuntu 18.04 from within Ubuntu 24.04 on a free 1TB partition I have on the same physical SSD? (Preferably while Ubuntu 24.04 is running). Or should I say, what is the best way of approaching getting Ubuntu 18.04 onto that partition more generally?
The reason I need 18.04 is because I need to compile firmware that demands the use of an old version of a particular toolchain?
Thanks.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

You give no clues as to what Ubuntu 18.04 system you're talking about; a Desktop install for example requires loads more space than a Server install (and you're not even close for desktop), and there are other install options too (docker images etc); however bionic is EOL or EOSS depending on architecture, and EOL/EOSS releases are off-topic on this community support site.

I meant a 1 TB partition

Install it on VirtualBox
